# How to extract string separated by blank spaces in windows command line batch commands

Tags: windows, git, cmd, command-line

I am trying to read the latest commit for a git remote repository using this command

```
git ls-remote https://repo.myrepository.com/scm/swc/project.git refs/heads/qa
```

it works fine and returns me something like this

```
5261626431661281d788382a1ed6ab1440fd93a8        refs/heads/qa
```

But I am not able to find online any way to extract only the commit hash from the returned string in command line

So basically I want to extract this string from the output of the command

```
5261626431661281d788382a1ed6ab1440fd93a8
```

I thought it would be very easy to find this information online, but the only answer I am finding everywhere is this

```
git ls-remote https://repo.myrepository.com/scm/swc/project.git refs/heads/qa | \ cut -f 1
```

But this does not work in windows command line, ofcourse because `cut` is not windows command.

Can anybody please help for windows command line version of it?

Comment: What is your constaint ? can you use git-bash ? do you have to use powershell ? or cmd.exe ?

Comment: @LeGEC - I am calling this command in C# code using Process so yes, cmd.exe is the way for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this command from `C#`, you can process the output in `C#` :

```
if (lines.Count > 0) {
   sha = lines[0].Substring(0, 40)
}
```

---

I imagine you are working with Windows. If `git` was installed with the standard windows installer (as opposed to : compiled from source), it actually comes with the standard linux tools (grep, cut, ...).

It just doesn't update the global `%PATH%` in your system to point at these tools - the main known issue is : there is a standard windows tool named `find`, which does not behave as linux's `find`, updating the global `%PATH%` for everyone would break the scripts that rely on windows' version of `find`.

One possible way to use them :

- find the directory which contains all the standard linux tools,
- run your `Process` command with a `PATH` environment that contains this directory

Comment: Thanks. Yes from C# I knew I can process the output but somewhere my requirement is to get the command output in exact final form.

Comment: compile a C# program, and then call from your main program using Process ? ;)

Comment: updated my answer, with one possible way to use the standard linux tools